# Simple question about derivative under Integral Sign

Tags: integration, ordinary-differential-equations

I'm doing a differential equation of the form $y'y = t(1+y^2)$, and after rearranging I'm facing this integral: $\int \frac{ y'(t)y(t)}{y(t)^2+1} dt$. Answers just separate it and solve $\int \frac{y}{1+y^2}dy$ - but where does the $y'$ go?

Comment: No, it is $\int\frac{y}{1+y^2}\,\mathrm{d}y$, not $\int\frac{y}{1+y^2}\,\mathrm{d}t$.

Comment: I should have noticed this sooner. Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

this is called "integration by subsitution" (google it, or look in your lecture notes).

In this case you would write:
\begin{align}
\frac{dy}{dt} &= y' \Rightarrow dy = y' dt \\
\int\frac{y'(t) y(t)}{y^2(t)+1} dt &= \int\frac{y}{y^2+1}dy
\end{align}

Note that on the right side there is no $t$ anymore. The integration is directly over $y$ as a new variable.

Comment: I am so stupid sometimes. Christ almighty. Thank you, this has saved me a headache.

Answer (score 0):

You can rearrange this to:
$$\frac{y}{1+y^2}\frac{dy}{dt}=t$$
$$\int\frac{y}{1+y^2}\frac{dy}{dt}dt=\int t\,dt$$
$$\int\frac{y}{1+y^2}dy=\int t\,dt$$
Now you may wish to make a substitution on the left to make this clearer :)